# C#/ SQL Server error 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-2008-r2

So, I'm getting the error as per my title line. Seems pretty self- explanatory, but my understanding is that objects within the "using" block are disposed of? This error appeared after another minor bug interrupted code execution, so perhaps I'm stuck with an open reader that I need to close or shut down? Any help would be appreciated?

```
public override long GetStatsBenchmark(String TableName)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sprocReturnDataPointBenchmark", this.sqlConnection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@benchmark",
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt,
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);
        SqlParameter inputParameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@tblName",
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Value = TableName
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(inputParameter);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return (long)outputParameter.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it reproducible or did it just happen one time when you were debugging?

Comment: @Bryan I've been stopping it at the error, rerunning, same error. I've tried while debugging cmd.Dispose, to no avail..

Comment: Are you doing anything else with `this.sqlConnection` somewhere else that could be impacting this?  It sounds like another command object somewhere else in your code could be using the same `SqlConnection` and it hasn't been closed yet.

Comment: @BryanCrosby I do use sqlConnection in other code, but all in the same "using" scope as my example. Am I wrong in my thinking that this releases the connection?

Comment: Sorry, I meant is there another `SqlCommand` somewhere in another method that is using `this.sqlConnection` that perhaps is not in a using block or did not have `Close()/Dispose()` called?

Comment: @BryanCrosby No prob. Yup. Other SqlCommands using this.sqlConnection. As far as I know (checking again, now) all in using block..

Comment: Check things like [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254509.aspx) are also being disposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that the code you have shown is the cause of the problem. While it is good practice to dispose of `SqlCommand` (`IDbCommand`) objects, in practice I have not found it to be necessary. What *is* necessary is to dispose of `SqlDataReader` (`IDataReader`) objects after you have finished using them. As the error message suggests, look for a usage of an `SqlDataReader` object in your code that is not being disposed. The exception may be thrown from the code you are displaying, but I would suspect that the cause is because of an `SqlDataReader` associated with the same `SqlConnection` used earlier in the program execution that has not been disposed.

Comment: Right you are. Thanks. I found an open reference out of 40+ that I didn't think was being called.

Answer (score 1):

An issue with the using clause is that it does not provide a way to process exceptions in the implicit try/finally block that the compiler generates for you.

You can
1) wrap your using clause with a try/catch, or 
2) manually code a try/catch/finally instead of using, calling Dispose in the finally block and adding exception handling in a catch block.

There are slight drawbacks to either technique, but either will work

Answer (score 0):

You can add MARS (multiple active result sets) to your connection string, to allow multiple recordset (or similar) open at the same time.

Add

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

or

```
MARS Connection=True;
```

to your connection string (http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) and this will allow multiple handles, but if the previous operation has been "interrupted" in an exception, try avoid using "USING" or use a try/catch inside it.